# how to set environment variable from file contents?

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, cygwin, windows-shell

On windows/cygwin, i want to be able save the PATH variable to file on one machine and load it onto the other machine;

for storing the variable i am doing:

```
echo %PATH% > dat
```

however, not sure how to load it later.

```
set PATH=???????
```

Thanks
Rami

Comment: Just use: `set /P PATH=< dat`

Comment: post your comment as answer and I'd vote it up.

Answer (score 17):

Just use: `set /P PATH=< dat`

You must note that `echo %PATH% > dat` insert an additional space after %PATH% value; that space may cause problems if an additional path is later added to PATH variable. Just eliminate the extra space this way: `echo %PATH%> dat`.

Comment: For me this only works for the first 1024 characters of the file. Sorry, I missed the fact this was on cygwin. Maybe it works better under cygwin.

Comment: @RussellGallop, did you find a workaround for this limitation?

Comment: `set /P` can only read 1024 characters. To read more, use `for /F` as shown in SpaceMonkey answer below.

Answer (score 6):

`echo %PATH%` will fail if the PATH contains an unquoted & or ^ (this is not likely, but certainly possible)

A more reliable solution is to use:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo !path!>dat
```

Then you can use Aacini's suggested method of reading the value back in

```
set /p "PATH=" <dat
```

Answer (score 5):

This might be evil but on Windows I am using this:

```
for /F %%g in (dat) do set PATH=%%g
```

and this to write the file because I had trouble with spaces

```
echo>dat %PATH%
```

Comment: You must use the "delims" option if you want to manage spaces: for /F "delims=" %%g in (dat)

Answer (score 3):

Being dependent upon Cygwin, how how about putting the command in your saved file, e.g.:

```
echo "export PATH=$PATH" > dat
```

Then sourcing the script later to set the path:

```
. ./dat
```

Note that "sourcing" the script (vs. just executing it) is required for it to modify your current environment - and not just new child environments.

Comment: on windows i had finally to do ' echo set PATH=%PATH% > dat.bat '; thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following sample works even with spaces and dot in the path value:

```
@REM Backup PATH variable value in a file
@REM Set PATHBACKUP variable with value in the file

@echo %PATH% > pathvalue.txt
@type pathvalue.txt
@for /f "delims=" %%l in (pathvalue.txt) do (
  @set line=%%l
)
@set PATHBACKUP=%line%
@echo %PATHBACKUP%
```